# How to incorporate flair model into presidio framework?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, flair, presidio

I was looking for some sample code/tutorial how to implement flair based model within the presidio framework and I found this https://github.com/microsoft/presidio/blob/main/docs/samples/python/flair_recognizer.py, but actually, it is not wroking. Has anybody have an experience with this topic?

Comment: Could you please share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share some code snippet on how you have tried. Alternatively, you may want to check the implementation from [this](https://huggingface.co/spaces/beki/pii-anonymizer/blob/main/flair_recognizer.py) link.